# GRUB is showing Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter error after fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.10 on Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3 in UEFI mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot, moklistrt

I just installed `Ubuntu 20.10` on my `Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3` in `UEFI` mode with Windows dual boot and now getting the following message at start:

```
Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

After a few seconds, Ubuntu is successfully boot. No errors appears later, system works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu installer incorrectly suggest what all `UEFI` systems has `Secure Boot` feature. But mine hasn't.

To correctly execute booloader and pass `Secure Boot` checks, Ubuntu use special package called `shim`. On UEFI systems without `Secure Boot` support it shouldn't be used in boot process.

The easiest way to remove it and rebuild grub, is to use `Boot Repair` app. Execute the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
```

You may run it through terminal

```
sudo boot-repair
```

but because it will ask you to execute few commands on terminal during repair, I'll prefer to run it from graphic interface.

Wait until Boot Repair will scan your system and then set the following advanced options:

- Main options

  - `[x]` Reinstall GRUB
  - `[x]` Use the standard EFI file
  - `[ ]` Backup and rename Windows EFI files
  - `[ ]` Restore EFI backups
  - `[x]` Unhide boot menu: X seconds
  - `[ ]` Repair file systems
- Check GRUB location is correct
- GRUB options

  - **`[ ]` Secure Boot**
  - `[x]` Purge GRUB before installing it
  - Uncheck all other options here
- Other options: leave all as is, but I will prefer to change one option:

  - `[ ]` Repair Windows boot files

then click `Apply`. Follow instructions provided by the app, execute required commands, then click `Follow` in UI.

Now just reboot.

P.S. If you want to see your GRUB menu during boot load process (by default it's hidden and available by `Esc` pressing or `Shift` holding) you may do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add or change

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.