# Black screen is shown instead of GRUB menu on Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3 with ASUS HD7850-DC2-2GD5-V2 (Radeon HD 7850) graphic card installed

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, graphics, radeon

After a clear installation of `Ubuntu 20.10` and [resolving issues with GRUB on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306738/grub-is-showing-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter-error-after-fresh-ins), I see just black screen instead of real GRUB menu (holding `Shift` button or pressing `Esc` doesn't help). Ubuntu booting successfully after default GRUB timeout expiration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a probably the following GRUB bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/545103.

To resolve the issue, update the default GRUB configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add or update

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=gfxterm
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES=vbe
```

then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot.